# Single word for "the act of passing possession and linear position to"

Tags: single-word-requests

**OLD TITLE:** *Single word for “moving an element of an order into another order at the same place?”*

Something similar to the word *move* would do the trick.

Imagine that I was talking about people (element) in a line (order)

"I **moved** Person A out of Line 1 to Line 2"

Now, this is nearly what I am looking for, except there is one other thing I need the verb to do, which is to emphasize the fact that it was moved to a corresponding place within the line/array.

To say this using the word "move" I would have to say:

"I **moved** Person A out of Line 1 ***at Line Position Alpha*** to Line 2 ***at that same position (Line Position Alpha)***"

that is to say, I recorded Person A's place in line, took him out of Line 1, and had him cut in line at the position I recorded, so he doesn't "loose his place in line."

The purpose of this word is to name a small section in a computer program that I am building. The program has these things similar to lines (called arrays), things similar to people in a line (called elements), and things similar to line positions (array indeces).

So, conclusively, what is the technical-term/word I am looking for?

**AUTHOR's NOTE:** I also posted this question on stackoverflow with a more-programming-emphasized side of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609019/word-for-moving-an-element-into-another-array-at-a-corresponding-index

**ANOTHER NOTE:** As [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) mentioned in the comments, I could use "extract (from)" and "insert (at)," but this would be a disfavor as I need both the "from" and "at" to be emphasized single-wordedly, because it will be used in a name, and lengthy names are well, just not efficient nor effective.

The name will be structured like "The *Move*-ment Process"

Comment: I would use *transfer* to express both "extract (from)" and "insert (at)" in a single word. I am not sure how to cram "at that same position" into the same word - perhaps *equitransfer*?

Comment: Just looked up _transferring_ (which is closest to getting a noun-form from this verb) in the dictionary, and it was defined as "the act of passing possession to," So perhaps the word for "the act of passing possession and linear position to" is what I am looking for. Let me go ahead and change the title of the question.

Comment: *transfer* is a noun too. One of its meanings is "an act of moving something or someone to another place". I believe this is closer to what you describe than your definition, which relates to the conveyance of property.

Comment: Perhaps I could use *lineotransfer*? I mean it is made up, but its for a name, so it doesn't have to be a real word, just one that is memorable, and *sounds* real

Comment: I am also having problems naming the _doer_ of this process. I think I will call it _lineotransferrant_

Comment: *Transpose* is also a candidate, although it has a different, specific meaning in mathematics. Personally, I would favour *transplant*, as most people associate it with organ transfer now, where the relative position (in the body) is maintained during transplantation!

Comment: In case of permutation, "shift" may fit: *the shift process*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *lateral transfer* though the phrase seems to have been usurped wholly by the HR domain for use in the context of employee "promotion" without change in salary.

There is a use of the phrase in science, engineering and technology as well.

See:
[Lateral Transfer Sliding Board V1 0 1](http://Lateral%20Transfer%20Sliding%20Board%20V1%200%201) (YouTube video)
*[lateral gene transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_gene_transfer)* Wikipedia

Comment: I have already made use of the word _lineotransfer(ence,ent; phenomenon, performer of action (respectively) )_, but since this has previous usage. I think it is better to encourage this one

Comment: Well, I suppose there is one minor difference. Lateral has closer tie in English to the word height, as opposed to Linear (lineo-) which has closer tie to the word line or order. And emphasizing that there is a "line" (array) is important. However, it could easily be dismissed

Answer (score 0):

*splice* is the verb you're looking for.  It covers moving contiguous sets of items between lists (your programming application) as well as genetic sequences, film, etc.